# Run multiple tasks on production server during boot up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

EDIT

Tried install God, but get `The server is not available (or you do not have permissions to access it)` on my dev machine.

really, only want to run 2 rake commands on passenger startup, is there an easier way?

---

Looking for something to help me get all my rake tasks organized and run during system boot / reboot on production server.

I have a very vanilla server on linode.com.  Ubuntu 10.04, rails 3.0.8, ruby 1.9.2p180 running nginx and redis.

Nginx and redis start automatically, but have to run rake tasks manually to start workers.

Any gems or scripts that can help me do this and send them to the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the God issue, check that there is no

```
w.uid = "xxx"
```

in your config file where xxx is a nonexistent user.